# Disable tooltip on certain points in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts line chart going and I have tooltips enabled, however, I would like to disable tooltips for the certain case where x=0.  Is there a way of doing this?  The closest that I have come so far is this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        if (this.x > 0) {
            return this.x;
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

This just creates an empty tooltip but there is still a popup.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok...just figured it out.  I just have to return `false` instead of `null`.

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        if (this.x > 0) {
            return this.x;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. now I'm trying to find out how to disable tooltip for one series, but fallback to the default tooltip for another series.

Comment: @ThePizzle figured it out already? I'm having the same problem here.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seem to work with `pointFormatter` when defining a custom tooltip for a given series. Returning false just prints false. Returning null shows an empty small box.

And formatter is not supported with series tooltip.

Comment: for anyone still looking for this, I found an answer that works with pointFormatter here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514555/disable-tooltip-for-one-point