# individual point settings in a scatter/line plot

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot, linechart

In a scatter HighCharts plot, I want to set some properties only for some data points of my series. Here is a toy example:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'line',
              data: [[1,1],
                     {x:3,y:2,marker:{enabled:false}},
            [4,1]]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

I need (in decreasing order of priority) the second point to NOT have:

1. the marker (already done in my code, working);
2. the tooltip (tried but without success, I don't know how to do it working)
3. the line coming from previous point (tried but without success, I don't know
   how to do it working)

Here is a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8U8nx/) version.

Comment: Series type property indicates what kind of a chart to be drawn on the canvas. And the default is line which draws a line chart. You said that you don't want the second point to have the type property, what does that mean I couldn't understand, do you want to have different kind of charts for each point? If you want to have a scatter type just replace line with scatter

Comment: To my knowledge, scatteplot series cannot have line. I need a line chart but with some "hole" in the line linking all the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second point, improvised from a similar answer:

> [Disable tooltip on certain points in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785886/disable-tooltip-on-certain-points-in-highcharts)

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        if (this.point.x != 1) { //enable for each point except the second point
            return this.x;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

for your third point you might try to use a trick. If you set the y value as null, that point won't be displayed in the line. So draw your line, and enter two data with null y values to create a lonely point on the chart.

> Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8U8nx/14/