# Disable tooltip for one point?

Tags: highcharts

my chart is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/

i know that if i want to disable the tooltip effect in highcharts, i need to add to my code this:

```
 tooltip: {
   enabled: false
   }
```

but i don't know how to disable it for only one point...

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Reading',
        colorByPoint:
        { color: "#ff0000"},

        data: [
            // [X, Y, Z]
            [1, 8, 1],
            [1, 9, 2],
            [1, 1, 5],
            [2, 7, 2],
            [2, 3, 4],
            [4, 5, 7],
            [4, 5, 8],
            [7, 3, 3],
            [7, 8, 5],
            [10, 7, 10]
        ]},{ ------ draw a line on bottom frame
            data: [[0,0,5],[10,0,5]
        ],
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.51)' 
        },  ------ end draw

           {  // ------ draw a point on (right edge) bottom frame
            data: [[10.7,0,5]],                
             dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,                    
                crop: false,
                overflow: false,
                 format: 3,
            }, 
            marker: {

                enabled: false,
                states:{

                    hover: {
                        enabled: false

                    }
                }
            }

    }]
```

how can i to disable the tooltip for the point that i addded ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable tooltip for specific points using `tooltip.formatter`. You will need to add some identifying attribute to the points that are not going to have a tooltip, and then check for that in your `tooltip.formatter` function.

For example, you could set your `data` like this (see first point):

```
data: [{x:1, y:6, z:5, noTooltip: true}, [8, 7, 9], [1, 3, 4], [4, 6, 8], [5, 7, 7]]
```

Then in your `tooltip.formatter` you can evaluate like this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        // If the point is going to have a tooltip
        if(!this.point.noTooltip) {
            // Mimic default tooltip contents
            return '● '+this.series.name+
                   '<br/>x: <b>'+this.point.x+
                   '</b><br/>y: <b>'+this.point.y+
                   '</b><br/>z: <b>'+this.point.z+
                   '</b><br/>';
        }
         
        // If tooltip is disabled
        return false;
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/04p61fbr/) (point that is disabled is at coordinates [1,1,0] in bottom left).

Comment: thanks! is that the only way to add "noTooltip: true" to point ? plaese see the code in first post :( my point is  "data: [[10.7,0,5]],"   and not "data: [{x:10.7, y:0, z:5, noTooltip: true}]"

Comment: Do you have any problem using `data: [{x:10.7, y:0, z:5, noTooltip: true}]`? It should be the same as `data: [[10.7,0,5]]`.

Comment: yes i know... but if i write  "data: [{10.7,0,5, noTooltip: true}]"  doesn't work... sorry

Comment: Did you implement the `tooltip.formatter` function?

Comment: If you open your console you have a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` because you have `{10,750,-0.3, noTooltip: true}`. It should be `{ x: 10 , y: 750, z: -0.3, noTooltip: true }`, if  those are your x, y and z values.

Comment: genius! this absolutely helped +1, just remember to add it at the same level as the chart option, not under plotOptions.series