# hightchart line and column chart , line not start with start of chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, cumulative-line-chart

here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkwvus8u/22/), you can see the black line start with column center,

how to that black line at starting of bar and end it to ending of bar ?

Like below image.
[image]

this is a simple task to look, but try all to do it but now working.

I try it with add data value by adding `[-1,7.6]`

see code ::

`{
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'line',
        data: [[-1,7.0], 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        step: 'center',
        rangeSelector: {
        selected: 0
            }`

but it show '-1' on xAxis see image

[image]

Please help :(

Comment: @Kamil Kulig made this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49448269/3200799). It's not working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [highcharts column chart with line, need line start at bar start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425790/highcharts-column-chart-with-line-need-line-start-at-bar-start)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Img]

This requirement is complex, use this steps .

1>Use Formatter to remove -1 and 12 in xAxis

2>Disable crosshair for xAxis (I updated to false)

3>Add fake column series for point -1 and 12.

4>Disable fake series legend.

5>Disable tooltip for particular point for all series using formatter (got idea form this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28516275/3898339) post).

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: [{
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ],
    crosshair: false,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.pos != -1 && this.pos != 12) {
          return this.value
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
      format: '{value}°C',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }
  }, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} mm',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,

    formatter: function() {
      if (this.points[0].point.noTooltip == false) {
        return false
      } else {
        var points = this.points;
        var pointsLength = points.length;
        var tooltipMarkup = pointsLength ? '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + points[0].key + '</span><br/>' : '';
        var index;

        for (index = 0; index < pointsLength; index += 1) {

          if (index == 0) {
            tooltipMarkup += '<span style="color:' + points[index].series.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + points[index].series.name + ': <b>' + points[index].y + ' mm</b><br/>';
          } else {
            tooltipMarkup += '<span style="color:' + points[index].series.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + points[index].series.name + ': <b>' + points[index].y + '°C</b><br/>';
          }

        }

        return tooltipMarkup;
      }
    }

  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    x: 120,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 100,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {

      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      pointPadding: -0.3,
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Rainfall',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' mm'
    }

  }, {
    name: 'Temperature',
    type: 'line',
    data: [{
      x: -1,
      y: 7.0,
      noTooltip: false
    }, 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6, {
      x: 12,
      y: 9.6,
      noTooltip: false
    }],
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    step: 'center',
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 0
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Rainfall',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    color: "#fff",
    data: [{
      x: -1,
      y: 50,
      noTooltip: false
    }, {
      x: 12,
      y: 55,
      noTooltip: false
    }],
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' mm'
    },
    showInLegend: false,
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Deep thanks for your efforts it will not working when you have dynamic data see this http://jsfiddle.net/jkwvus8u/40/

Comment: true it is not dynamic follow @Kamil Kulig answer. If you want to use in dynamic way you have to set the above trick dynamically